# Group by multiple timestamps; join months but keep separate values

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I need to grab the # of settled and unsettled orders by month. Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(MONTH(time_settle), "/", YEAR(time_settle)) as month_settled, count(*) as settled 
FROM payment_order 
WHERE time_settle IS NOT NULL 
AND datediff(time_settle,NOW())>-90 
AND datediff(time_settle,NOW())<+90 
AND account_id=28 AND current_state !="deleted" 
GROUP BY MONTH(time_settle);
```

The result is:

```
month_settled | settled
-------------------------
6/2014        |   1
9/2014        |   10
12/2014       |   1
```

And unsettled I use time_due:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(MONTH(time_due), "/", YEAR(time_due)) as month_due, count(*) as unsettled 
FROM payment_order 
WHERE time_settle IS NULL 
AND datediff(time_due,NOW())>-90 
AND datediff(time_due,NOW())<+90 
AND account_id=28 
AND current_state !="deleted" 
GROUP BY MONTH(time_due);
```

The result is:

```
month_due     |  unsettled
-------------------------
8/2014        |   1
9/2014        |   8
10/2014       |   2
```

I need a result that looks something like this:

```
month         |  settled |  unsettled | total
----------------------------------------------
6/2014        |    1     |     0      |   1
8/2014        |    0     |     1      |   1
9/2014        |    10    |     8      |   18
10/2014       |    0     |     2      |   2
12/2014       |    1     |     0      |   1
```

Any ideas? How can I do a group by months if my sum criteria are two different months? I need the settled transactions to be grouped by time_settle and the unsettled transactions to be grouped by time_due.

Comment: can you post a sqlfiddle with the data that results in those counts?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ec1f7/1 -- heres the sample. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok try this

```
SELECT t.month, 
    coalesce(t1.settled, 0) as settled, 
    coalesce(t2.unsettled, 0) as unsettled,
    coalesce(t1.settled, 0) + coalesce(t2.unsettled, 0) as total
FROM
(   SELECT CONCAT(MONTH(a.t_month), "/", YEAR(a.t_month)) as month
    FROM
    (   SELECT COALESCE(time_settle, time_due) as t_month 
        FROM payment_order
    )a
    WHERE datediff(a.t_month,NOW())>-90 AND datediff(a.t_month,NOW())<+90
    GROUP BY month
)t
LEFT JOIN(SELECT CONCAT(MONTH(time_settle), "/", YEAR(time_settle)) as month_settled, count(*) as settled FROM payment_order WHERE time_settle IS NOT NULL AND datediff(time_settle,NOW())>-90 AND  datediff(time_settle,NOW())<+90 AND account_id=28 AND current_state !="deleted" GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM time_settle)) t1 
    on t1.month_settled = t.month
LEFT JOIN(SELECT CONCAT(MONTH(time_due), "/", YEAR(time_due)) as month_due, count(*) as unsettled FROM payment_order WHERE time_settle IS NULL AND account_id=28 AND current_state !="deleted" GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM time_due)) t2 
    on t2.month_due = t.month;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7dfe/1)

Comment: @Federico the problem with this is you need to join on your concatenated month/year.. but the issue with that is you don't have the same months for the different dates.. so you have to get the months first then join to them.. a little complicated but it works lol... Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I've been looking at the script. I have one question here -- if I change the range from +/- 90 days to +/- 60 days, I get some empty values.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7dfe/2 -- https://www.dropbox.com/s/qsf9yoxk3fxjr1t/Screenshot%202014-09-08%2011.42.17.png?dl=0 --- Why would 12/2014 show 0 | 0 | 0 whereas 11/2014 doesnt show up.

Comment: @Federico Well 60 days from now wouldn't reach december so thats probably why its not showing up.. if thats what you're asking

Comment: Yeah the result is good. My question was just why would 12/2014 show up with 0's where as 11/2014 doesn't show up. The reason is probably that there exists one with a date in 12/2014, but it isnt counted ( hence = 0). Whereas there is no date existing in 11/2014 so it doesnt even grab that month to tally up 0's.

Comment: @Federico do you want it to show 0's for each month? it pulls out the dates in the table which don't include november (since there isn't one in november) there is in december but none for your counts so its just 0's..

Comment: so if you want to see 0's for each month I can work up a solution for you with that.. if not then you will just need to limit the date inside the first subquery with the alias t

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60911/discussion-between-federico-and-john-ruddell).

Comment: @Federico did you want to talk about the query more?

Comment: @Federico come back to the chat lol.. i made a few changes that I need to explain

Comment: @Federico OOPS sorry I acidentally removed the GROUP BY lol.. its supposed to be GROUP BY EXTRACT() that way you are grouping by not only the month but also the year to account for months beyond just one year.. edited :)

Comment: Any idea why adding `ORDER BY month DESC` doesnt seem to sort it correctly? https://www.dropbox.com/s/oh79o1kspnnvvet/Screenshot%202014-09-10%2017.56.25.png?dl=0 -- it should be 8/2014, 9/2014, 10/2014 but it is showing 9/2014, 8/2014, 10/2014....